# I tried to write the code to count the number of characters in the line of the file but the ifstream object doesnot take the line from the file

Tags: c++, file-handling

This code doesnot take string of file count in ofstream object file1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream file1("count.txt");
    string sentence;
    getline(cin,sentence);
    file1<<sentence;
    ifstream file2("count.txt");
    string wordscount;
    while(getline(file2,wordscount))
    {
        cout<<wordscount;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to flush it.

Answer (score 2):

You did not close the stream, so the file may be not existing on the FS when new stream file2 is opened. Add the line

```
file1.close();  // <-- new line
ifstream file2("count.txt");
```

Comment: Note that [`flush()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) should also work.

Comment: Thank you I actually have concept that destructor itself close the file object but its not the case if we do multiple operations on file which i know from your comment and it worked